# Flutter release compilation mode not adding cryptography libs

Tags: flutter, dart, cryptography

I am facing a problem with Flutter when building Apps.

If I build the non release (debug) for my App and I get the android build and send to my mobile phone I can use the app developed without any issues.

So when I try to build as release and navigate across some cards, login for example, I get
"No suitable CryptoEngine could be loaded"

My intention is to fix this on dart/flutter layer so the build would behave the same for iOS and Android (assuming here).

I tried on gradle build for Kotlin to add bouncy castle but did not have success.

Any ideas about what is happening and how to solve that?

Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 41456452f2 (6 weeks ago) • 2024-01-25 10:06:23 -0800
Engine • revision f40e976bed
Tools • Dart 3.2.6 • DevTools 2.28.5